# How can i do operation between "datetime.timedelta" and "int"?

Tags: python, datetime, int, operation

I'm trying to do '>' between a datetime.timedelta and int.This is my code:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()      
date = int(input("Enter date"))
month = int(input("Enter month"))
year= int(input("Enter year"))
date1= datetime.date(year,month,date)
difference=today-date1
print((difference.days),"days")
if (difference)>14:
    print("The difference is not allowed greater than 14")
```

My input is right but the system shows that i cant do compare between 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'.

```
Enter date04
Enter month04
Enter year2020
36 days
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khooz\OneDrive\Documents\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if (difference)>14:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

How can i do '>'between these two objects?Thanks for anwsering!!XD

Comment: I assume this is Python? check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects): `timedelta` objects have a couple of attributes which you could use or e.g. the `total_seconds()` method.

Comment: Why don't you keep using `difference.days`? :)  It's an integer as you see and you can compare it with other integers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do '>' between these two objects?

To compare `timedelta` and `int` objects you need to convert one to the other:

```
if difference > datetime.timedelta(days=14)
```

or

```
if difference.days > 14
```